# Sum function with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to sum the variable "Hill-Burton Funds", grouping by "stateyear":

```
ds['Hill-Burton Funds'].replace(",", "")
ds['Hill-Burton Funds'].astype(str).astype(int)
ds['hbfunds'] = ds.groupby(['stateyear'])['Hill-Burton Funds'].sum()
```

Despite first converting "Hill-Burton Funds" from an object to an integer, when I use sum() it is returning the variable ("hbfunds") that simply aggregates the numbers together instead of adding them(ex. 2000 and 2001 are becoming 20002001 instead of 4001). Please any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to re-assign the variable to ds: `ds['Hill-Burton Funds'] = ds['Hill-Burton Funds'].astype(str).astype(int)`

Comment: Hmm, I tried that and it didn't help...

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
ds['Hill-Burton Funds'] = ds['Hill-Burton Funds'].replace(",", "").astype(str).astype(int)
ds['hbfunds'] = ds.groupby(['stateyear'])['Hill-Burton Funds'].sum()
```

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: It's now returning it as "NaN"

Comment: You can find the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html). I think it would be `.sum(skipna=True)`. But probably your conversion to integers does not work properly.

Comment: @slovakia111 If you are getting NaN, then it means there's missing values in your data. You need to check the values in the data to see what's really happening there.